# How to format my date to Default format

Tags: java, date, java-8, format

I am using java 8
I have an sql server type of date like this

```
2016-01-20T00:00:00.000
```

The default date format is :

> new Date() ==> Wed Aug 30 11:03:30 CEST 2017

I would like to format my date to the default one.

thanks

Comment: there is no default format... you need to use a DateTimeFormatter

Comment: A date in Java has no format

Comment: The generally recommended way is: get yourself a JDBC 4.2 compliant database driver. Then, depending on your requirements for time zone, either transfer `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` from your `ResultSet` and to your `PreparedStatement`. And then don’t worry about format.

Comment: And avoid the long outdated `Date` class. The modern classes mentioned in my previous comment are much nicer to work with.

Comment: This Question is unclear. Are you parsing a string? Are you retrieving a date-time object from database, and if so, exactly what type? Are you trying to capture the current moment? Also, *all* of those have been handled already on Stack Overflow. Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LocalDateTime` with its [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--).

```
String s = LocalDateTime.now().toString(); // ISO standard representation

// LocalDateTime to old Date:
Date date = Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

// Old Date holding time to LocalDateTime:
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(),
        ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Of cause with an SQL `PreparedStatement`, you could simply call `setDate` without the detour via String.

Answer (score -2):

This code will do exactly what you want. Only requires you to get the value as `String`:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String date = "2016-01-20T00:00:00.000";
Date d = new Date(dateFormat.parse(date).getTime());
System.out.println(d);
```

produces the following output:

```
Wed Jan 20 00:00:00 CET 2016
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Today we have so much better.

Comment: I thought the asker was asking for the format `2016-01-20T00:00:00.000` as output. I admit it was very unclear, though.

Comment: thanks, it worked xtremeBaumer

Comment: @OleV.V. try using something like `LocalDateTime` in java 7 or below. therefore in my eyes its still good to know how to do it before java 8

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, the question was clearly about Java 8. While we can discuss whether your answer would be helpful for another question, IMHO it isn’t here. Certainly not without any reservation about Java version.

Comment: In Java 6 and 7 there's a [backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp) for Java 8 new API (so you can use `LocalDateTime`). And for Java 5, there's [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) (although in maintainance mode, still a better alternative than the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` API). I know that there's still lot of legacy code that can't be migrated yet, so we still have to live with `SimpleDateFormat` for a while. But it's also good to know that we have better alternatives, not only for the newest versions of Java.

Comment: @Hugo We *can* live without `SimpleDateFormat`. Write new code in java.time, and at the end convert to the legacy types required by old code via new methods added to the legacy classes.

Comment: @OleV.V. And I thought the OP asked about the format `Wed Aug 30 11:03:30 CEST 2017` (because they said that's the "default format"). The question is really unclear...